Can I customise the notification email for wordpress comments?
Is there a way to customise the subject line of a comment notification email in Wordpress? Here's my problem: my comments generate emails that get sent to my admin mailbox and that works fine. But I want to forward them to a gmail address and that fails. Even if I manually forward them they say they've been sent but they never arrive. I've tried this on a non gmail email target and the same thing happens. Other wordpress emails such as when I change the admin password or fill in a contact me form work just fine.
I compared the source of the emails that work and don't work and it comes down to the subject line. The comment notification subject line looks like this:
Subject: =?us-ascii?Q?[Roger_Parkinson]_Please_moderate:_"Dummy_post?=

And the ones that work look like this
Subject: [Roger Parkinson] New Admin Email Address

I assume the ?us-ascii... stuff is to handle the fact it contains quotes. Fair enough, I guess but I don't think I'm going to talk Google into changing their policy to process these messages instead of rejecting them. So is there a way I can convince my Wordpress installation to change the message? Dummy_post in this case is the name of my post and I can live with it not being in the subject line at all, or maybe just remove the quotes.
I have looked at several plugins that looked like they might do this but they turned out to be more interested in generating notifications for other events rather than customising the message for an existing event.
Is this possible? I'm okay editing PHP but I'd take a while to hunt out where it needs to change and the next update will overwrite the change unless I do something clever.
EDIT: I managed to refine the problem down to it being more related to the colon than the quotes. I can trigger it by simply putting a colon in a message to my gmail from my non-gmail address.

Yes, there is a dedicated hook,comment_moderation_subject, however, although using it to set static text might make your mail flow, I doubt that the header encoding is actually a problem at Google since it was introduced in RFC 1342 and is very, very common. Most likely Google is trapping/rejecting it for spam reasons.

Thanks @ChrisHaas. I will experiment sending the same message from somewhere else.
